# What does it mean when a hold short sign is out of service?

Tags: airport, taxiing

I prepared for "SELCAL" exam and in one of the routes I heard such information as

> RW 32 hold short sign at TWY L is out of service.

I just don't understand this phrase. I appreciate it if someone help me.

Answer (score 6):

It means that you might not be able to see the hold-short sign when you are on Taxiway L approaching Runway 32.

Perhaps the light inside the sign is not working and needs to be replaced, or perhaps the sign itself is missing because it has been run over by a snowplow.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it means that the hold short surface painted markings have faded out...but the term 'Out Of Service' I have heard applied only to lights, for example.

Comment: If the NOTAM was for faded surface markings it would say that the surface markings were faded. This is for an inop sign. Not really sure how you would think they mean the same thing.